# How to get binded value key on click in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having a md-select dropdown list with binded data by using ng-repeat,when on button click I need to get key value of that selected value (json key of that value).

Here is my js:

```
 $scope.checklist= [{ "val": 1, "txt": "one" }, { "val": 2, 
"txt": "two" }, { "val": 3, "txt": "three" }, { "val": 4, 
"txt": "four" }, { "val": 5, "txt": "five" }, { "val": 6, 
"txt": "six" }, { "val": 7, "txt": "seven" }, { "val": 8, 
"txt": "eight" }, { "val": 9, "txt": "nine" }, { "val": 10, 
"txt": "ten" }, { "val": 11, "txt": "eleven" }];

  $scope.searchTerm;
  $scope.clearSearchTerm = function () {
      $scope.searchTerm = '';
  };
 $scope.getDropdwnSelectedValue = function (val) {
       alert(val);
  }
```

Html code:

```
<div layout="row">
        <md-input-container>

            <md-select ng-model="selected.key" md-on-close="clearSearchTerm()" multiple="" style="width:300px;">
                <md-select-header>
                    <input ng-model="searchTerm" type="search" placeholder="Search for ..">
                </md-select-header>
                <md-optgroup label="list">
                    <md-option ng-value="chkLst.txt" ng-repeat="chkLst in checklist|
          filter:searchTerm" >{{chkLst.txt}}</md-option>
                </md-optgroup>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="getDropdwnSelectedValue (selected)">Get Value</md-button>
```

Comment: If you wish to roll back my good changes, please either ping me at `@halfer` or flag for a moderator. I am fairly confident that a mod will support my changes, since I have removed chatty material and fixed case and spelling errors. Would you like to provide an explanation for this now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a mistake in `ng-repeat="chkLstin checklist | ..."` should be `chkLst in checklist | ...`. And, you don't need to have a function call to see your values while developing. Just use it like `<pre>{{selected.key}}</pre>` in your HTML to see if you get the value in `ng-model`.

Here's [**working codepen**](http://codepen.io/tanmayrajani/pen/QpXBQX?editors=1010#0)

Answer (score 0):

Your scope variable has the selected value. Initialize the scope variable as `$scope.selected = {}` and you will get the value in `$scope.selected.key` since `selected.key` is set as your `ng-model`

Comment: This is wrong. It's initialized by the view due to E2E binding. No need to initialize it in the controller.

Comment: In some cases during run time there will be an error while accessing the scope variable object if that is not initialized. Normally in strict mode. So always I prefer initializing scope variable before accessing it.

Comment: Yea, you could do it but its not needed. The user is able to easily access `$scope.selected.key` without init it in the controller.

Comment: Always best coding practice is to declare an object before using it. Declaring a variable will never make any change in the user accessibility. Also in future if the user moves to a strict mode, using without declaration will definitely throws an error.

Comment: I think you did not understand E2E binding of AngularJS yet. It makes no difference if you init a var in view or in the controller. Your approach is incorrect. The user must not declaire `$scope.selected = {}` in the controller to be able to access `$scope.selected.key`.

Comment: If you still not believe me try this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zZVLLo?editors=1010